# Materializecss select multiple angular2 formControlName

Tags: angular, multi-select, materialize

How to select default values (I mean values that come from database) with materializecss and Angular2 using formControlName ? I've a list of observations and for each one a list of attendees, I want to select all attendees in the list of users.

```
<select class="icons" [materializeSelectOptions]="users" materialize="material_select" formControlName="attendees" multiple >
     <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user" class="right circle">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

To get attendees :

```
 this._route.params.switchMap((params: Params) =>
      this._observationService
          .getObservation(params['key']))
          .subscribe((data) => {
               data.attendees.forEach((userSelected) => {
                    this.selectedUser.push({
                         id: userSelected.attendees,
                         name: userSelected.name
                    });
               });
       this.observationForm.patchValue(data);
 });
```

To get all users :

```
this._userService.getList()
    .subscribe(users => {
        users.forEach((user) => {
           this.users.push({ email: user.email, name: user.name });
        });
     });
```

This is user object :

```
{
    createdAt: 1486419737973,
    email:"gage@ge.fr",
    lastConnection: 1486419737973,
    name: "Gage",
    role: "membre",
    updatedAt: 1486419737973     
}
```

This is attendees part of observation object :

```
{
    ...
    attendees:[
       0: {
         email: "bla@bla.fr"
         name: "Bla" 
       },
    ],
    ...

}
```

If I change :

```
<option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user" class="right circle">{{user.name}}</option>
```

with this :

```
<option *ngFor="let user of selectedUser" [value]="user" class="right circle">{{user.name}}</option>
```

It displays and select only attendees users.

Comment: How is your `component`? Your question is a bit incomplete.

Comment: @developer033 OK, I've edited my post.